# Can the LLC for a YouTube channel be formed in any us state?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

If I want to form my LLC in a state like Nevada or Wyoming because of the stronger protections, but I live in Florida will I have to foreign file in Florida because I'm uploading YouTube videos from florida?

Or is that that not really enough for them to say I'm operating in florida?

Comment: The answer to the title question is easy. Yes it can be formed in any U.S. state. The body text questions about foreign filing are less easy.

Comment: Incidentally, the belief that Nevada or Wyoming provide stronger protections from liability incurred by the business is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can form an entity in any U.S. state and every other state under the full faith and credit clause of the U.S. Constitution, is required to treat that entity as valid.

Foreign filing is required where an entity does business. If work is actually done for a website in Florida, for example, then it is doing business in Florida.